# Prevent direct access PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 script. That's :

1. registration.html
2. process_registration.php

Sometimes someone open the link direct into process_registration.php, so how can I prevent that ?

Process_registration.php function is to save the data get from input from registration.html.

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101895/how-to-stop-direct-execution-of-a-php-page-using-htaccess-rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
if (!isset($_POST['field'])) {
  die();
}
```

at the top of your process_registration.php file.

Of course, replace `field` by one of your existing fields in your form.

If you're against flooders that does register several accounts using scripts, you may use a [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) field on your registration form, or use [protections against crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257584/how-to-detect-fake-users-crawlers-and-curl).

Comment: $_POST can be sent also with php curl so I don't think that this is the most efficient solution.. For better security I think you can verify also the referer

Comment: Referer can also be set by cURL

Comment: Everything a browser can send, can be emulated. So if you need real protection, you will need a more complex solution. Like generating one time passwords (hashes).

Answer (score 3):

Just another method:

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
  exit("Direct access not allowed");
}
```

Just more flexible with the object names. For extra security, you should put this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="9957374" name="hiddenvalidate" />
```

and in your script:

```
if (!isset($_POST['hiddenvalidate']) || $_POST['hiddenvalidate'] != 9957374) {
  exit("Direct access not allowed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current request is a POST type (if you use a form)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

and you can also check if all required variables are set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_POST` array in process_registration.php for this like :

```
if(!isset($_POST['yourvariable'])){
//Redirect to registration page
}
```

You can also use [PHP Session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for it. If session is not set then redirect user to registration page.

Answer (score 1):

I like the way `Joomla` handles this issue.

On every php page in Joomla, you will see the following code:

```
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die; // it's a config setting
```

Only the top-level pages have this variable included in them. All other files, if opened directly, close, thereby preventing any accidental misuse/data loss.